# Looking for information on "Pouzet's lemma"

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am looking for information on "Pouzet's lemma," which I learned about in [slides of Chris Hartman on Sperner's lemma](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/%7Ehartman/pouzethex.pdf). I have copied the statement of the result from that site. I would love any published references, and in particular a more direct proof (since the proof on that site goes Sperner's lemma $\Rightarrow$ Connector theorem $\Rightarrow$ game of Hex $\Rightarrow$ Pouzet).

> **Def:** In $d$-space, call the unit vectors along the axes
> $\{u_1, u_2,\dotsc, u_d\}$. A **box** of the integer lattice points is the set
> of points $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2, \dotsc , x_d)$ satisfying $a_i \le x_i \le b_i$, $1 \le i \le d$.
> We call two points **neighbors** if their coordinates differ by no
> more than one in any position.
>
> **Pouzet’s Lemma:** For any mapping $f$ from the lattice
> points of a $d$-dimensional box $A$ to the set of unit vectors
> $\{\pm u_1, \pm u_2,\dotsc, \pm u_d\}$ such that $\vec{x} + f(\vec{x})$
> is in $A$ for all $\vec{x}$ in
> $A$, there exist two neighbors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ such that $f(\vec{x}) = −f(\vec{y})$.

Comment: See Douglas West's book *Combinatorial Mathematics*, page 804; as well as Joseph Zaks, “Towards a simpler proof of the Brouwer fixed point theorem.” *Geombinatorics* **5** (1995), 35–37. I believe the result is named after Maurice Pouzet, but I'm not sure.